# IP canonical URL issue

Tags: redirects, canonical-url, ip-address

So I did a search engine optimization test today and one thing it came back with was:

> Your site's IP XX.XXX.XXX.XX does not redirect to your site's domain name. This could cause duplicate content problems if a search engine indexes your site under both its IP and domain name. Consider using a 301 re-write rule in your *.htaccess* file so that your site's IP points to your domain name."

I have looked but I can't seem to find a clear answer on how to do this, I need to know what I would put into the *.htaccess* file? There was something over at [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9251748/how-to-do-ip-canonicalization-in-htaccess) but I'm not sure that's right.

Comment: Did any of the answers help you?

Answer (score 2):

This warning is innocuous since IP addresses can serve multiple hosts and are not expected to redirect to one particular domain.

Prior to being concerned with this, you should first check if accessing the IP address even returns the same content as your domain. Even if it does however, search engines like Google will not penalize your site for duplicate content unless it appears to be spammy (e.g., intentionally scraping site content from another site), as indicated here:

[Cutts on similar website content, multiple domains: Duplicate or safe?](http://www.brafton.com/news/cutts-on-similar-website-content-multiple-domains-duplicate-or-safe)

Comment: I saw the "SEO tool" in question linked from reddit. It was full of incorrect advice so should not be trusted.

Answer (score 1):

You probably want something like this depending on what your canonical URL is:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
# Redirect IP/non-canonical domains
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^11\.22\.33\.44 <-- Server IP here.
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

You may already have something similar in your *.htaccess* if you redirect `www` -> `non-www` or vice versa.

*edit* - please remove the `<-- Server IP here` once you insert your own server IP.